# What is fix for Dpi value remains same for all android emulators?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am currently testing on Android emulators where dpi value remains to be same 320dpi for all sort of emulators where I varied it from 240dpi to 441dpi.I have added a sample screenshot while setting up for 440dpi.Could anyone help me to fix on this.Thank a lot.

[image: Sample screenshot while setting up for 440dpi]

Comment: Are you talking about changing the monitor dpi value?

Comment: check Scale display to real size>> click on the "?" mark >> set your monitor screen size and current resolution>> monitor dpi will be set to 100%.
give your AVD Screen Size to almost half of your monitor screen size, AVD will fit the screen.

Comment: @IronBlossom : Nope I still get dpi as 320 only for all Custom emulators..what next I have to do..